# Tensorflow data validation for uniqueness

Tags: validation, tensorflow, tensorflow-data-validation

I'm using Tensorflow data validation and want to make sure a column has no duplicate values. But it seems Tensorflow's data validation doesn't have a feature like Deequ's `isUnique` function to check uniqueness? Is there a way to define uniqueness in Tensorflow's schema? I read the documentation [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/metadata/blob/master/tensorflow_metadata/proto/v0/schema.proto) but still can't find anything for uniqueness.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

till now, tfdv is allowing just to check if number of unique values within a column is in an interval. attribute to do that are feature.unique_constraints.max & feature.unique_constraints.min